# Getting Error when trying to connect AWS Aurora Postgre cluster from spring boot app

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

I am trying to connect to AWS Aurora (Postgre) cluster from spring boot app using following properties

```
spring.datasource.driver.class.name = org.postgre.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://a2-xxxxx.cluster-xxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
```

but I am getting following error -

```
*Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.postgresql.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:postgresql://a2-xxxxx.cluster-xxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.<init>(DriverDataSource.java:110) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.initializeDataSource(PoolBase.java:331) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.<init>(PoolBase.java:114) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]*
```

Following are my maven pom.xml contents -

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should read the jdbc [documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html).

If the host is specified, the url needs a / at the end.  If the database you are connecting to has a different name than the user, you also have to put the name of the database after the /.  Even if they are the same, it's a good idea to include the db name because that default behavior is a bit confusing.